# Dropping/creating procedure causes transaction log to empty

Tags: sql-server-2016

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make sure database is in Full recovery mode
2. Run procedures (containing insert, updates) causing transaction log to grow
3. use DBCC SQLPERF(logspace) to check transaction log size
4. drop/create used procedures
5. Observe that the Log space used dropped (in my case from about 20% to 0.5% with Log size unchanged)

I am unable to determine what is going on.

NOTE: This is a dev machine, nothing escept management studio queries interact with the database

Comment: Have you ever done a full backup of the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server acts like simple mode until you've established the log chain. This means that it will be happy to discard log information from already-committed transactions.

Paul Randal goes into a little more detail about the mechanics behind this here, but basically, this behavior will stop once you start proper backups:

- [New script: is that database REALLY in the FULL recovery mode?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-is-that-database-really-in-the-full-recovery-mode/)